# Got Neo4j syntax error using the same code from "Learning Neo4j" by Rik Van Bruggen

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I used the following code from Rik's [book](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/learning-neo4j-graph-databases) (page 105):
[image]

However, I got the following syntax error:
[image]

I assume the symbols quoting **Relationship Type** is the backtick `

May I ask how to correct the syntax errors here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably only a typo error in the book or maybe an old-syntax style. You should put parenthesis in `from` and `to` variables:

```
load csv with headers from "file:/your/path/to/rels.csv"
as rels
match (from {id: rels.From}), (to {id: rels.To})
create (from)-[:REL {type: rels.`Relationship Type`}]->(to)
return from, to
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add parentheses like that :

`` CREATE (from)-[:REL {type:rels.`Relationship type`}]->(to) ``

Before v3.0, parentheses in patterns were not mandatory, now they are.